# Unable to read all contacts from the android phone

Tags: android

I want to read all the contacts from the phone but i am unable to read all the contacts .

Those contacts that are related to any account are not be imported.

Kindly help me

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Comment: this only gives you contacts with a phone number, i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this intent code -

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(contactPickerIntent);
```

It shows all the contacts in my address book. Try out this.

Answer (score 1):

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```